# On Mac's Cocoa, how do you get the RGB value of any point on the screen?

Tags: cocoa

I tried

```
  CGPoint pt;
  pt.x = x;
  pt.y = y;

  NSColor* color = NSReadPixel(pt);
  float colourValue = [color greenComponent] + [color redComponent]+ [color blueComponent];
  printf("%f\n", colourValue);
```

but it always print out 0.0000

(if you know a method to "set" the value of a pixel on the screen too, thanks)

Comment: Are you sure your x y values are valid ? Also it should probably be `NSPoint pt;`, not `CGPoint pt;` ?

Comment: I tested several x, y values such as 0, 0, and 500, 500, and 600, 600, etc...  I will try NSPoint afterwards... my program is very different right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This CocoaDev page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?GettingTheColorUnderTheCursor) has several approaches for getting a pixel's color. According to the example code there you would need a transparent graphics context in the right location to be current before NSReadPixel would work.